# SQL SUM of a column with the union of two tables is incorrect

Tags: c#, sql, sum, db2, union

I have two location tables:

1) One table will list all locations that have a part in it. So, one row will have LOCA  PARTB   QTY 5   another row will have LOCA PARTC QTY2, and another possibly, LOCB  PARTX  QTY3.. So when QTY = 0 for a row, it get removed. So there are instances where a location will no longer be listed in this table

LOCQTYS TABLE:

```
Location | Part  |QTY
LOCA     | PARTB | QTY 5 
LOCA     | PARTC | QTY2
LOCB     | PARTX | QTY3
```

2) I have another table that lists all the names of locations that exist regardless if there is a part assigned to it or no parts assigned.

This table just lists the name and a description.

LOCNames TABLE:

```
LocName | Description
LOCA    | Storage 
LOCA    | Storage
LOCB    | Base
```

So I am attempting to list all locations to user and display 0 if no parts are assigned or display the sum of all parts assigned.

```
example:
Loc1 30
Loc2 12
Loc3  0
Loc4  6
```

My sql statement is as follows:

```
    sql = @"SELECT locnam, 
            Sum(locqty) 
            FROM  (SELECT locnam, 
                          locqty 
                   FROM   " + DatabaseUtility.LibraryList.I + @".locqtys 
                   UNION 
                   SELECT locdnam AS LOCNAM, 
                          '0'     AS LOCQTY 
                   FROM   " + DatabaseUtility.LibraryList.I + @".locnames) R 
           GROUP  BY locnam 
           ORDER  BY locnam ASC";
```

The problem is the count is off...

```
So what should be,
example:
Loc1 30
Loc2 12
Loc3  0
Loc4  6
```

ends up being:

```
example:
Loc1 25
Loc2  8
Loc3  0
Loc4  3
```

The sum is lower than the actual... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use "UNION ALL" instead of "UNION"... Union eliminates duplicates.

Comment: Yea that did it!  Didn't take into consideration there could be different rows with the same Location and QTY... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a `left join`:

```
select l.locnam, coalesce(sum(lp.locqty), 0) as locqty
from locations l left join
     locationparts lp
     on lp.locnam = l.locnam
group by l.locnam;
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not familiar with the coalesce function. I will have to play around with this one.

Comment: in this case you can use use coalesce function or ifnull function or case instruction

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for???
create table loc
(location  varchar(10),
part  varchar(10),
qty int)

insert into loc values 
('loca','part a', 10),
('loca','part b', 20),
('locb','part c', 30),
('locc','part d', '')

select location, sum(qty) from loc group by location[image]

Answer (score 0):

in Sql Sums Always use "Isnull(  column_name, 0.00)"  and " union all "

/*------------------------*/

```
SELECT isnull(locnam) as locnam,
Sum(isnull(locqty,0.00)  as locqty
            FROM  (SELECT isnull(locnam,0.00) as locnam 
                          isnull(locqty,0.00) as locqty)
                   FROM   " + DatabaseUtility.LibraryList.I + @".locqtys 
                   UNION all
                   SELECT isnull(locdnam,0.00) AS LOCNAM, 
                          '0.00'     AS LOCQTY 
                   FROM   " + DatabaseUtility.LibraryList.I + @".locnames) R 
           GROUP  BY locnam 
           ORDER  BY locnam ASC
```